# ASP.NET Kill Session By Id

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, sessionid

My application has a control of User Permissions, because not all users can access full website. At this moment, all those permissions for an specific user are stored in his session, 'cause It would be a problem for me to search at Database every Post Back.

The problem is that when I remove a permission, user can still access the page, and only when he closes the browser, the update take effect.

Is there a way to Kill an specific Application Session by the ID, forcing user to Log in again?

Comment: Although it's not exactly what you're looking for, if you're changing permissions that frequently, you may want to have a look at changing the session length via Page.Session.Timeout property, as it's defaulted to 20 minutes.

Comment: I got your point, but I can't do that. The permissions are not frequently changed, but I need that when it occurs, the update take effect at the same moment, forcing user to log in again. Unfortunately, some of user functionality take too much time for him.

Comment: Brute force approach if you are using in-memory state is to restart the app on permission changes... Note that it will not work with proper out-of-process provides like SQL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
"Is there a way to Kill an specific Application Session by the ID, forcing user to Log in again?"
```

No. You can only access the Session object of the user doing the current request (i.e. yourself), not other users Session objects.

So, you need to store the id of the user somewhere else, for example in a static collection. When the user makes the next request you can check if the id is in the collection, and update the permissions or log out the user.

Another alternative would be to keep the permission objects of all currently logged in users in a static collection as well as in their Session variable. That way you would be able to change the permission object without accessing the Session object of that user.

Using static variables in a web application of course comes with the usual precautions. As multiple threads can access it, the access has to be synchonised. Also, as Alexei Levenkov pointed out, if you have multiple servers you have to keep the data synchonised between the servers.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa. I'll try your solution, as I realize I can't access Session object of another user.

Comment: +1 on "not other users Session objects"... I'd be very careful with "Static collection" for permissions - as any kind of cache it requires code to keep in sync with actual storage/across machines (if more than on serves the site). It may be easier to swallow performance hit of permission check if correctness of permission checks is important.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Good point. I added a note about the risks with static variables.

Comment: Thank you all. The solution you two gave to me worked fine. For those who have the same problem, the solution is working with static objects, taking care of Sync.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `Session.Abandon();` or `Session.Clear();`

or `Session.SessionID[int index];`

store the  particular user session value in  this  and   then  use  `Session.Abandon();`   and  `Session.Clear();`

For killing a particular session try using `Session.Remove("key");`

Comment: This kills the entire session, not just one particular piece.

Comment: @KarlAnderson:- Thats correct!! Updated my answer as well. Thanks for the suggestion!!!! :)

Comment: Probably not the scenario OP have in mind - not many users will execute "take all permissions from me" willingly, it seem more "take permissions away from that user"...

Answer (score -2):

To remove a particular piece of `Session`, then use `Session.Remove()`, like this:

```
Session.Remove("YourKey");
```

Note: This removes the value and the key from `Session`, while you may see people use `Session["YourKey"] = null;` that will only remove the value, but leave the key. This may or may not be what you want, but just wanted to point out the distinction.