# How to kill session of any user on website

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I want to know is there any way to kill any specific user session on my web site. On using out Proc Session management and saving session in SQL server in asp.net web site.

Like admin has changed some rights of user and he want to kill session of that specific  user on website. is there any why to do this?

Comment: According to this link there is no way to do so. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450892/asp-net-kill-session-by-id I do not recomend messing with the SQL Server Session database.

Answer (score 1):

it seems there is no direct way to kill any specific user session. you need to bit customize your logic.

Yes, You can kill specific session variable with the help following code snippet ..

```
Session.Remove("key");
```

To Remove/Kill any specific user session do the following steps:-

1) While Login the user, keep User name and session Id in database table (i.e. Login_Log table).

2) Add Below event in global.asax

```
Application_AcquireRequestState
```

In that event check that current user session Id is exits in Login_Log table or not? if Not exists then kill the user session as below:

```
 Session.Clear();
 Session.Abandon();
```

It will kill the user session.

3) if You want to kill specific user Id, just delete respective user record from Logi_Log table. it will automatically kill on next (any) event.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`Session.Remove("key");`

Comment: for every user, key is same. cant do that

Comment: There is no way key can be same for every user. It's based on the `key` the users session values are distinguished.