# End a session remotely MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I found something to help me get a list of the active sessions from [List all active ASP.NET Sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9706287/4171534).

What I now need to do, if possible, is be able to end any of the sessions from this list inside my application. The purpose of this is for user support, I don't have access to the IIS server hosting the app so I can't just jump on there to end sessions. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `Abandon` method on the session, this will cause the `End` event to rise.
Check it out it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524310(VS.90).aspx).

Comment: @DavidGettins exactly

Comment: @DavidGettins where you looking for ending any session or just selected ones?

Comment: @DavidGettins you can't. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450892/asp-net-kill-session-by-id